# Can I trigger Google Sheets scripts in a particular sequence?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I've altered a script that gets data from MailChimp and then displays it in Google Sheets. However, the the data comes out in a random order, rather than ordered (e.g. by "campaign date") and also creates duplicates.

So I added two scripts that

1. Clear the previous data
2. Sort in date order

I want to run these scripts in a specific order so:

1. The cell ranges clear
2. The data imports from mailchimp
3. The data is rearranged in date order

Ideally I'd like to refresh this data every 15 minutes. What's the best way to do this? I can post my code but it's quite bloated and messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar problem which I have solved by creating a "parent" function that runs all the other functions in order. For robustness I have also included a simple logging function that logs this to a sheet so I can easily see that the functions have run. However, if you're running this every 15 mins that could quickly get out of hand, so you could either bin the logging, or use the built-in Logger ([see reference here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger))

```
function runAllFunctions() {
  logit("Clearing data");
  clearCellRange();
  logit("Data Cleared. Importing MailChimp Data");
  importMailchimpData();
  logit("MailChimp data imported. Reordering data.");
  orderData();
  logit("Data reordered. Update complete");
}
;

function logit(message) {
  var logBook = SpreadsheetApp.openById("<insert ID here>")
  var logSheet = logBook.getSheetByName("Log")
  logSheet.appendRow([new Date(),message]);
};
```

Comment: I should have added - to run every 15 mins you can set up a trigger. It's the fifth button along in the script editor - looks like a little stopwatch.